# Abstract Construct Signatures and instantiation with type hierarchy

Tags: typescript

Given the code below:

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract getName(): string;
  printName() {
    console.log("a")
  }
}
class Derived extends Base {
  getName() {
    return "";
  }
}
```

There is at least one error for each of three scenarios below. But I am able to run it. Why is it?

What functionality of the code below is? Is it a correct way?

1 [link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygEwFYCMWBQBDAI0QBdp8BjE0CgG30UVACEHJQBvXUUI08qqADmkEgDl8AW0gAKAJSp%20ASwB2QgNzdQAB2irxU2XM5aeFOCsRxakAHS04QmQCJ8zuVoC%20ub3QZMAERglADdIABNQSAAPEkgVcKZWRHYuHhEDaXkTHh5oUQBXaBVQZ2dNHm9vEFAAWnqKApJ62twAMwKVKiULYXzRGSoEVBIAT21IODaWNmM0mgtSUFVSfC72AF5QFUgAdxoSBHkK5csSNYo7XX0JLLlNb1whfpIZIL0w8Punl5lkyHuQA)

```
function greet(ctor: Base) {
  const instance = new ctor();
  instance.printName();
}

greet(Derived);
greet(Base)
```

2 [link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygEwFYCMWBQBDAI0QBdp8BjE0CgG30UVACEHJQBvXUUI08qqADmkEgDl8AW0gAKAJSp+ASwB2QgNzdQAB2irxU2XM5aeFOCsRxakAHS04QmQCJ8zuVoC+ub3QZMAERglADdIABNQSAAPEkgVcKZWRHYuHhEDaXkTHh5oUQBXaBVQZ2dNHm9vEFAAWnqKApJ62twAMwKVKiULYXzRGSoEVBIAT21IODaWNmM0mgtSUFVSfC72AF5QFUgAdxoSBHkK5csSNYo7XX0JLLlNb1whfpIZIL0w8Punl5lkyHuQA)

```
function greet(ctor: typeof Base) {
  const instance = new ctor();
  instance.printName();
}

greet(Derived);
greet(Base);
```

3 [link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=36&pln=14&pc=10#code/PTAEAEFMCdoe2gZwFygEwGYAsBWAUAIYBGiALtAQMamiUA2BiioAQo5KAN56ijFkVqoAOaRSAOQIBbSAAoAlKgEBLAHbCA3D1AAHaGonS58rtt6U4qxHDqQAdHTjDZAIgIv52gL54f9RswAIjDKAG6QACagkAAepJCqEcxsiBzcvKKGMgqmvLzQYgCu0KqgLi5avD4+IKAAtA2UhaQNdXgAZoWq1MqWIgVistQIqKqQAO6gOQC8AHys7CbptJZkoGpkBN0c06Bjk8PQCpXrVqRblPZ6BpLZ8lo+wgOkssH64RH3eE+QgymQ9yAA)

```
function greet(ctor: new () => Base) {
  const instance = new ctor();
  instance.printName();
}
greet(Derived);
greet(Base);
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-construct-signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is at least one error for each of three scenarios below. But I am able to run it. Why?

Unless you enable [the `--noEmitOnError` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError), the compiler will still emit JavaScript even if type errors are present.  This JavaScript code will look very much like the TypeScript code with the static type system has been [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) (and with possible [downleveling](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#downleveling)).  Features of the static type system such as interface definitions and type annotations *do not* affect runtime behavior.  All three of your scenarios will be emitted as something like

```
function greet(ctor) { // type annotation erased
  const instance = new ctor();
  instance.printName();
}

greet(Derived);
greet(Base);
```

and therefore will act the same at runtime.  [TypeScript *preserves* the runtime behavior of JavaScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-from-scratch.html#runtime-behavior).

---

> What is the functionality of the code below? Is there a correct way?

The differences among the three scenarios occur at the type level and not at the emitted JavaScript.  While they behave the same at runtime, they convey different *intents* to the compiler. The errors imply that they are all incorrect in some way or another: the code conflicts with its own stated purpose, and the compiler is telling you what is wrong.  The "correct" way has to do with what your actual intent is, so it is subjective.

---

Let's look at the first one:

```
// version 1
function greet(ctor: Base) {
  const instance = new ctor(); // error! Base has no construct signatures
  instance.printName();
}
greet(Derived); // error! typeof Derived is not a Base
greet(Base); // error! typeof Base is not a Base
```

This is the most incorrect.  You have told the compiler that `ctor` is an *instance* of the `Base` class, not a *constructor*.  And therefore when you write `new ctor()`, the compiler is warning you that you seem to be trying to construct something that might not have a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures).  And calling `greet(Derived)` and `greet(Base)` are both errors because neither the `Derived` nor the `Base` class constructors are *instances* of `Base`.

It seems unlikely that you really want `ctor` to be an instance, since you use it like a constructor.

---

Okay, now for the second one:

```
// version 2
function greet(ctor: typeof Base) {
  const instance = new ctor(); // error! Cannot construct abstract class
  instance.printName();
}

greet(Derived);
greet(Base);
```

This is a little better; you are telling the compiler that `ctor` is the same type as the value named `Base`... that is, it is an abstract class constructor whose concrete subclasses can construct instances of `Base`.  You can think of an `abstract` constructor as a "non-constructable constructor"... it can have `static` properties like a class constructor, but you should not directly try to call `new` on it.

Anyway, now you can call `greet(Derived)` and `greet(Base)` because concrete constructors are assignable to abstract constructors (but not vice versa).  That's because you are allowed to refrain from constructing a concrete constructor.

But inside the implementation of `greet()` there is a problem. You told the compiler that `ctor` is abstract, but then you go ahead and call `new ctor();`.  That's an error.  The fix here is either to change `ctor`'s type, or to refrain from calling `new ctor()`.  I assume you want to call `new ctor()`, so we will move on:

---

Finally:

```
// version 3
function greet(ctor: new () => Base) {
  const instance = new ctor();
  instance.printName();
}
greet(Derived);
greet(Base); // error! Abstract constructor is not newable
```

This is the closest to correct.  By giving `ctor` the type `new () => Base`, you are saying that `ctor` is *constructable* with zero arguments. This explicitly lets you call `new ctor();` with no errors.  And the call to `greet(Derived)` is fine, because `Derived` is indeed a concrete class constructor which takes zero arguments.

The error here is in the call to `greet(Base)`.  `Base` is not constructable, and so the compiler warns you.  The right thing to do here is not to call `greet(Base)`.  Comment it out or erase it.

---

I will end by coming back to the question

> I am able to run it.  Why?

with a slightly different answer.  Without changing the types of version 3, let's imagine if we changed the second line in the implementation of `greet()`:

```
// version 4
function greet(ctor: new () => Base) {
  const instance = new ctor();
  console.log(instance.getName());
}
```

There is no compiler error here.  Since `ctor` is supposed to be a concrete constructor, it will construct a concrete instance of `Base`, which must have a `getName()` method that returns a `string`.  Calling `instance.getName()` should be fine, right?

```
greet(Derived); // ""
```

Okay, so far.  But how about:

```
greet(Base); // compiler error 
// RUNTIME ERROR! instance.getName is not a function
```

**Here is the problem**.  You were able to run `greet(Base)` before because the `greet()` implementation *just so happened* not to rely on any of the differences between abstract and concrete constructors.  But now you see why the compiler complains: you are using an abstract constructor in a place that expects a concrete one... which can lead to runtime errors.  The type signature of `greet()` is `(ctor: new () => Base) => void` and represents a *contract* between the caller and the implementer.  The implementer will only use features of `ctor` which it knows about, and the caller will only pass in a `ctor` with those features.  If the caller violates the contract, then the implementer is not at fault.

---

So the right version of this code is, presumably, not to call `greet(Base)`:

```
function greet(ctor: new () => Base) {
  const instance = new ctor();
  instance.printName();
}
greet(Derived);
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=56&pln=25&pc=38#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIKiQzwIDmOEAcsALY4AUAlAFwLkCWAdlQDcxBAAco-ek1ZsCIkrAD2fMIuQ4AdMkVUWAImB62IgL6EzKNBgAiOCQDccAEwQ4AHhBx8nGbGDxEJDRSzOxyJCRQtACuUHwIenrCJGZmhHzSYKJweADyfAEiAGbRfPA8ytRRtCzwilBcfjiygRFKKoj8kMBleAC8CAUA7kgQ9eyCCAD0U65QUPUAhFi4CAAWaIOKSMrk0ZRgPFQZELE4YPIIXRA9sJrikgyhbMkIaUHVECy2Ds4v07M7AsoMsIABPUQ4RRFBA-HiOFw8DB8RSIYArfwiKifFhNf4zObA0EQqEwppXZGo0gYnDmQj0jLMLI5BAAFSG21aJTKEAq8WxOBqdQaCHBkOhNJal3akCuHVu-UGOBGwomAMJSwQAGEeijEDLoPs0eBoHB9ah0JdrgqNA8+CEZK93lVBV84QiXlicXjhGlGedsnc2WtquEENzypUBUKxiLhggwn0AHySsMKXadeW9BADeOqz0ROXdXq2iT2p6O0xe13fOzwv6vaNfH3qoGagCCJoo+ozUCN9QpW0Qw1A6jp6UygbwADFFLEwxHeVGccKuPHEym8Wmdh0izds7nlaNxgW2rs1JptLprSXghX2KezB8a+6G+rEtWai2CQAlACqdCsgAkgAsgAoggYE-j+uQ-ssN53Bod7SIOerUoufLjv6zJBtO9YLqUkb8iusZrkeG6pq06a7ghip5rGExWlmiF2g6jEpJ+bp1h6vpAA)

Comment: Wow, this is the most detailed answer I have ever seen. Thanks very much in advance. I have read a few times, but I still need to read external links few more times before I reply or mark it as answer.

Comment: I am an experienced C# dev, have read once https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro.html , but there still are some concepts in TS that are not understood. Do you think it is a good learning resources? Are there any better resources? Or I should re-read some topics in the `handbook` that I don't understand fully? Appreciated your advice in advance again.